# Call a JavaScript function name using a string?

Tags: javascript

How can I hook up an event to a function name I have defined as a string?

I'm using Prototype.js, although this is not Prototype-speficic.

```
$(inputId).observe('click', formData.fields[x].onclick);
```

This would result in JavaScript complaining that my handler is not a function. I would prefer not us use `eval()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

[Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) can be used to access any object's properties or functions.

If the function is in the global scope, you can get it using the window object:

```
var myFunc = window[myFuncName];
```

This also works within the `this` scope:

```
var myFunc = this[myFuncName];
```

Comment: ...or scope[myFuncName] in general

Comment: Yup, as long as you have a handle to the scope somewhere, this'll work

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a Node.js module?

Answer (score 9):

I have worked on this problem, as I needed a function like this. Here is my sandbox code, not thoroughly tested, but can be a startpoint for others.
Note that there is one eval() in the code as I couldn't figure out how to bypass that step, maybe a javascript quirk and cannot be done in any other way. Let me know if there is a way to get rid of eval() here!

```
executeFunctionByName = function(functionName)
{
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).splice(1);
    //debug
    console.log('args:', args);

    var namespaces = functionName.split(".");
    //debug
    console.log('namespaces:', namespaces);

    var func = namespaces.pop();
    //debug
    console.log('func:', func);

    ns = namespaces.join('.');
    //debug
    console.log('namespace:', ns);

    if(ns == '')
    {
        ns = 'window';
    }

    ns = eval(ns);
    //debug
    console.log('evaled namespace:', ns);

    return ns[func].apply(ns, args);
}


core = {
    paragraph: {
        titlebar: {
            user: "ddd",
            getUser: function(name)
            {
                this.user = name;
                return this.user;
            }
        }
    }
}

var testf = function()
{
    alert('dkdkdkd');
}

var x = executeFunctionByName('core.paragraph.titlebar.getUser', 'Ikon');
executeFunctionByName('testf');
```

Comment: To get rid of the eval you could navigate the namespaces from the window object: `var func = window; for(var i=0;i<namespaces.length;++i){ func = func[namespaces[i]]; }`

Comment: Thanks Ikon.  I tried many ways, this answer will solve my problem.

Answer (score 8):

... or this[myFuncName];

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps?

```
setTimeout ( "myFunc()", 1 );
```

Answer (score 5):

Just an `eval` would do the job

```
var call = eval("method_name").call(args);
```

Comment: Great! this worked... thanks;
You forgot . in between.

`var call = eval("mathod_name").call(args);`

Answer (score 3):

```
window.myFunction === window["myFunction"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `formData.fields[x].onclick` holds the name of a global function? If so try:

```
$(inputId).observe('click', window[formData.fields[x].onclick]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what the onclick property contains or what type it is? I assume this is prototype specific stuff, as "fields" does not exist in DOM forms.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call a string function with arguments, do this:

```
window[stringFunctionName].apply( window, arrayOfArguments )
```

You can use `scope` in place of `window` if preferred

Answer (score 0):

update:---
use ES6 export and import

a.js

```
const fn = {
  aaa: function() {
    //code
  },
  bbb: function() {
    //code
  },
  //codes ....
  nnn: function() {
    //code
  }
}

export default fn
```

b.js

```
  import someFn from './a'
  //eg
  const str1='aaa'
  const str2 = 'bbb'

  someFn[str1]()
```

---

- `eval('str')` (obsolete feature https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features )
- `setTimeout('str')`  `setInterval('str')`
- `window['str']` (but...sometimes,global object is not window)
- `new Function('str')`

These methods above always not be recommend by some reasons, but they are really convenient to use.
These methods below are safe, but really not conveninet to use.

- switch...case (or if...else)

  ```
  switch(str){
      case 'str1': 
          fn1()
          break
      case 'str2':
          fn2
          //and so on
  }
  ```
- put functions in a object

  ```
  const fn={
      str1:fn1,
      str2:fn2
      //and so on
  }
  fn[str1] //call function
  ```