# Call function via string?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have a string variable `js_inject` and I am looking for a way to call the `js_inject()` function via the string. Is there any way to do this other than the example below? I am really looking to do this without conditionals.

```
var myString = 'js_inject';

moderator(stringVar){
  if(stringVar == 'js_inject'){
   js_inject();
  }
}

moderator(myString);
```

Comment: Have you try `eval(myString)`? Where my `myString = 'js_inject()'`. It might be simplistic, but that should work.

Comment: Except eval is evil. A script kiddy could very well alter this javascript code and kill his own browser...

Comment: @GolezTrol *A script kiddy could very well alter this javascript code and kill his own browser* ... looks like a strong argument in favor of `eval`

Comment: Always great to see this question.  Again.  And again. 496961, 359788, 912596, 1451145, 1144297, .... :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call a JavaScript function name using a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496961/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-name-using-a-string)

Comment: @Kooilnc I was kidding a bit in that comment, but I'm serious about eval. Not because it could be abused, at least not really in client side Javascript, but it does help you write code that is complex and hard to debug. A little function call is not a problem, but sooner or later you find yourself generating complete functions in strings and parse those. Eval is best to be avoided at all, because there's mostly ever a better way. And if you really can't find one, okay, then you're excused. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a global function, you can write `window[stringVar]()`.

Answer (score 2):

A function you declare in the global scope becomes part of the `window` object, so you should be able to call this:

```
window['js_inject']();
```