# How add function name to handler click?

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I have a button and I have function which should execute on click.

example:

```
<button id="button1">bla bla</button>

<script>
var justFunctionName = "function1";
var function1 = function()
{
alert("!");
}

$("#button1").click(justFunctionName);

</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496961/call-a-javascript-function-name-using-a-string

Comment: Why not just call `function1` directly?  Why are you going through the step of using a variable  name for it?

Comment: in real code I declarate this function in an attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HTML

```
<button id="button1">bla bla</button>
```

---

### jQuery

```
var justFunctionName = "function1";

function function1()
{
    alert("!");
}

$("#button1").on("click", window[justFunctionName]);
```

---

### [See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pUwWG/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#button1").click(justFunctionName);
```

should be

```
$("#button1").click(function1);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var justFunctionName = "function1";
```

This is assigning the **string** *function1* to the **variable** *justFunctionName*.

If you were to do: `console.log('justFunctionName');` you would end up with the following result:

`>function1`

**Therefore this variable assignment is completely irrelevant for what you are hoping to achieve.** Instead of just assigning a variable to a function you are assigning a variable to a variable which is assigned to a function.

---

Now take a look at what you are doing here:

```
var function1 = function () {
  alert("!");
};
```

This is assigning a **variable** *function1* to the function doing the alert. In this instance, think of the variable as a **reference** to the function. In order to have the button trigger the alert, you need to call the *reference to the function* (in this case function1):

```
$("#button1").click(function1);
```

Comment: He wants to be able to call a function only with a name, the answer of Code Maverick seems to do the tricks. I can see it comming handy if, for exemple, you need to call a certain function depending of an attribute, for exemple ValidatePhone() or ValidateEmail() depending of the type of an object instead of calling Validate() and having a switch case that determine wich function to call.