# Call a factory by name in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to js. I have a big web app, potentially will have more than ten factories.

Here is my code. All the factory and service are in the same module

here is an example of factories

```
.factory('A', function(){
        return function A(){
           this.number;
           this._id= new Date().getTime();
           this.type = "A";
        };
    }).factory('B', function(){
        return function B(){
        this.type= "B";
        this.number;
        this._id= new Date().getTime();
        };
    })
```

And I have a service which creates new instance of factory object. the `addUnit()` function actually map to users click, so the `type` probably be `A`, probably be `B`. I know I can have functions for each of `A` and `B`, but because of the potential number of factories, i hope i could use only one creation function which takes type as a parameter and create new object according to the type.

```
   .service('myService', ['A','B',
    function(A, B){    
        this.addUnit = function(type) {
            console.log(typeof A);
            var myUnit = new window[type]({   //ERROR!!
                'number' : 3,
            });

            return myUnit;
        }

        addUnit("A");
}])
```

However, the console could print out `typeof A` is function, but i got an error `window[type] is not a function`.

SOLUTION:
Thanks @Claies ' suggestion, updated my service as below and works!

```
    .service('myService', ['A','B',
         function(A, B){    
          var $injector = angular.injector(['moduleName','ng']);
            this.addUnit = function(type) {
                console.log(typeof A);
                var myUnitFunc = $injector.get(type);
                var myUnit = new myUnitFunc({
                  'number' : 3,
                });

                return myUnit;
            }

           addUnit("A");
    }])
```

Comment: your question isn't really clear.  `typeOf A` and `typeOf "A"` aren't the same.  one would be a function, the other a string.

Comment: @Claies sorry about the typo. updated

Comment: what is `window`? how is it supposed to relate to these factories?

Comment: @Claies Well... that is my question. I console typeof A just to make sure the dependency is correct. window["A"] is supposed to convert a string to a function, but it doesn't work for me.....

Comment: @Ting: In angularjs you can obtain a provider (service/factory) through dependency injection. If addUnit is defined inside a controller/service, you can inject A into that controller/service and you will be able to call functions on A. Can you provide the whole source/scope where addUnit is defined so we know what you want to achieve?

Comment: I've never seen this `window[type]` syntax before.

Comment: @Claies here is a ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496961/call-a-javascript-function-name-using-a-string

Comment: @Ma3x updated my code. all are in same module,

Comment: well that will never work in angular, since putting things in the global scope isn't recommended, and definitely cannot happen for angular objects like factories.  I guess that's the reason I've never seen that used, since the global scope is such a bad practice.

Comment: @Claies all right. What is commanded to do if i want to convert a string to a function not in global scope....

Comment: sorry the commands in my previous comment weren't complete and probably wouldn't have worked; you definitely need to use `$injector`, but I've never needed to do this before, so I don't know the exact syntax.

Comment: @Claies thx!!! it works!!!!

Comment: @Claies updated post why I do this..... if you have any suggestions, pls let me know.

Comment: since I removed the comment which didn't have the correct syntax, you should consider making a self answer showing the syntax you used, to help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$injector`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) if you want to instantiate providers by their name (providing their name as a string).

```
.service('myService', ['$injector', function($injector) {

  this.addUnit = function(type) {

    var instance;

    if ($injector.has(type))
    {
      var typeConstructor = $injector.get(type);
      instance = new typeConstructor();
      instance.number = 3;
    }

    return instance;
  }

}])
```

Here is a working sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/t4ILB4CV11Lni8pLGQ9j

Comment: Though I figured out solution by @Claies suggestion, I'll give you credit. Thanks for your working example!

Comment: Good. This will serve as an answer for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `service` not `factory`.

```
.service('A', function(){
```

And the later code is wrong. I even can't guess what were you going to do. There is only one instans of service/factory.

Comment: it still gave me error : 'window[type] is not a function'

Comment: @Ting, anyway you are doing something awful.

Comment: why? do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Ting, see my other answer.

Comment: I think you just need a JS Object.. `function(n){this.name=n}`... I think using a factory is overkill/wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
.constant('A', function A(number) {
  this._id = Date.now();
  this.type = "A";
  this.number = number;
})
.constant('B', function B(number) {
  this._id = Date.now();
  this.type = "B";
  this.number = "number";
})

.service('myService', ['A', 'B', function (A, B) {
  var constructors = {A:A, B:B};

  this.addUnit = function (type) {
    var C = constructors[type];
    return C && new C(3);
  };
}]);
```